# RecyclerView Card expands in both directions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView with CardViews in it. When the user taps on a card, it should extend, showing a list of views below it. But, when it expands, it expands both downwards as well as upwards, leaving a blank space above the relevant content.

[This is what the expanded card ends up looking like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PG6v.png)

My layout file looks like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="event"
            type="com.example.android.productiville.calendarApiService.Event" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#1C1C1C"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taskName"
                android:layout_width="276dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/work_sans"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/taskName"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:taskName="@{event}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dayOfWeek"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/work_sans"
                android:text="@string/taskDay"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/taskName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/taskName"
                app:taskDay="@{event}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/work_sans"
                android:text="@string/startTime"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/taskName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/taskName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dayOfWeek"
                app:startTime="@{event}" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/editTaskButton"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:insetLeft="0dp"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetRight="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:cornerRadius="30dp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_create_24px"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:iconPadding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/addSubTaskButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addSubTaskButton"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/addSubTaskButton"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:insetLeft="0dp"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetRight="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:cornerRadius="30dp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:iconPadding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/closeEditPanelButton"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:insetLeft="0dp"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetRight="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:cornerRadius="30dp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
                app:iconGravity="textStart"
                app:iconPadding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/addSubTaskButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addSubTaskButton" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandableLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/taskName"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/subTasks"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

I am unable to make it so that the card only expands downwards. I would appreciate some direction here. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the "taskName" TextView and the "addSubTaskButton" Button were constrained to both the top and the bottom of the ConstraintView, and the height=wrap_content was resizing the card such that these views remained centered as per these constraints. Removing these constraints solved the issue.